# Wordpress Advanced Search

Tags: php, wordpress

I had created a custom search page containing the code

```
<?php 
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '{$_GET['frmdate']}' AND post_date < '{$_GET['todate']}'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where');
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <p><?php the_title(); the_date() ?></p>

<?php    endwhile; ?>
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**My Aim is Search posts with *'keywords' between 'Two Dates'***

my search variables passing through **url** like this

```
www.something.com?page_id=372&s12=lorem&s13=ipsum&frmdate=2012-03-01&todate=2012-06-12
```

with my Current code to filter the result between two date is Working perfectly when my url is looks like this `www.something.com?page_id=372&frmdate=2012-03-01&todate=2012-06-12`

when iam adding `&s=lorem` isn't work both keyword and date filtering. even I add it (&s=lorem) alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated My code with the below one **its working fine with my all requirements**, Not sure if there is an another smarter way

```
<?php 
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    if(isset($_GET['frmdate']) && isset($_GET['todate'])){
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '{$_GET['frmdate']}' AND post_date < '{$_GET['todate']}'";
    }
    if(isset($_GET['s12'])){
        $where .= " AND post_content LIKE '%{$_GET['s12']}%' " ;
    }
    if(isset($_GET['s13'])){
        $where .= " AND post_title LIKE '%{$_GET['s13']}%' "    ;
    }
    //echo $where;exit;
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where');
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <li>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <div class="monthDate"> <span class="date"><?php the_time('M d,Y H.i'); ?></span> <span class="month"><?php comments_number();?></span> </div>
        <p><?php content('100'); ?></p>
    </li>

<?php    endwhile; ?>
<?php remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a custom page, you may want to just alter the search template that's available in the WP template hierarchy. Please see [this post](http://codeblow.com/questions/wordpress-search-queries/) for more information.